# Error When Using If Else Statement To Chage the Content View

Tags: android

I have a setting that when clicked should change the content view of the class.  When I run it on my device the else part works but with the setting changed to follow the if statment it crashes.  Why is this?

**Sherman Class**

```
public class Sherman extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean theme = getPrefs.getBoolean("theme_key", false);
    if(theme == false) {
        setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_DarkActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.sherman_light);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.sherman);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adViewSherman);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}
**Setting**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/settings" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The `super` call should *almost always* be the first call. Also, you typically shouldn't change the `View` this way. Take your condition and use an `Intent` to go to the `Activity` you want and set the `View` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling `setContentView()` *after* `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: I tried this out and it still didn't work.  I will try making a seperate activity for it instead.

Comment: @user3499194 What kcoppock says is right. If it's still crashing it's likely that you have additional issues -- please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: My eclipse was having issues today so I had to reset a few files so I just rewrote them from scratch.  It ending up working.  It couldn't have just been cleaning the project because I had done that many times.  Anyways I did have to put it after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)